# file .htaccess acceso a sitio en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, apache, .htaccess

Buenos días estoy viendo un sitio en php pero no se esta direccionando las paginas de forma adecuada en la carpeta del sitio existe un archivo .htaccess pero no lo entiendo muy bien, alguien por favor me puede ayudar para poder entenderlo

**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**

Comment: El archivo .htaccess de tu web será como la tabla de los mandamientos para el servidor Apache que cumplirá estrictamente lo que se le indique en ese archivo. Si esta mal redactado, no te funcionará el sitio (generalmente error 500 en el servidor).
Que comportamiento esperas en tu sitio exactamente con ese .htaccess ?

Comment: Buenos días gracias por tu colaboración, al parecer debería abrir login.php pero sale error 500, el sitio esta hecho usando el framework codeigniter.

Comment: Todo es relativo, no tengo conocimiento del árbol de estructura de codeigniter de tu proyecto asi que no sabria donde están tus archivos. Como ayuda te podría indicar que existen depuradores online de .htacces. Por ej. https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/   por ahi te ayuda a solucionar eso.

Comment: No sé si ya lo hayas solucionado, pero mi archivo .htaccess de codeigniter lo tengo de la siguiente manera:   

`Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /nombre_de_proyecto  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]`